# Include AWS API Gateway generated SDK in NPM managed project

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, npm, webpack, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a ReactJS app that will be utilizing the API Gateway to access backend resources.  I've generated a Javascript SDK of my simple test API which accesses DynomoDB and am trying to include it into my Node/NPM development environment/project.  I'm using NPM to manage dependencies.  The generated API has no exports or require statements so I'm having issues using it in my project.  Is there a guide that indicates how to properly include the generated SDK into a project that uses NPM to manage dependencies and Webpack to bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the generated JS SDK is frustrating to use with Webpack and other bundling strategies. The simplest solution is to include these as script tags as mentioned in the documentation (you still have control over your index.html in React and Webpack).

If you prefer to import them so that they are handled by your Webpack config, you should be able to wrap them in a single module and use Webpack's `export-loader` to export values defined in the global scope of the dependencies. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html for more details.